# GHC - Mac OS X - ld: unknown option: -no_pie

Tags: macos, haskell, linker-errors, ghc, ld

When I try to compile a simple Hello World in Haskell and compile with
    ghc --make Main.hs
I get:
    Linking Main ...
    ld: unknown option: -no_pie
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.8. I used to be able to compile without this error, but I haven't used GHC for a while, so I must've installed or broken something in that period.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688002/error-with-cabal-mac-ossnow-leopard-ld-unknown-option-no-pie

Comment: @DonStewart: There is no answer on that question and the comments don't help much. Plus, I think his problem is a little different than mine, because he is trying to install a package and I am just trying to compile a simple program.

Comment: There we go. I had recently reinstalled an old backup of XCode, and thus an old ld. An update of XCode allowed my ld to accept the -no_pie flag.

Answer (score 1):

Leopard got rid of no-pie for a period: http://trac.macports.org/ticket/34064

As the comments note, upgrading xcode/ld to more recent versions enables the flag.